# Create a rounded BlockArrow

Tags: wpf, silverlight, expression-blend

Is it possible to create a rounded BlockArrow in WPF ?

I was looking for CornerRadius property but this property does not exist for BlockArrow.

Example :

- Green : Rounded arrow (target)
- Black : Not rounded arrow  (xaml)

[image: Rounded arrow]
[image: Not rounded arrpw]

Comment: Would you please give a visual or further clarification on 'rounded'?  Do you mean the arrow shaft is bent for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to edit the control template for the BlockArrow and do the rounding yourself.  My instinct is that this won't be an easy task.

edit: Laurent to the rescue!  Try [one of these arrows](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2009/08/31/56-vector-arrows-in-xaml.aspx) instead of the block arrow.

Comment: That was I was thinking... Thanks for the link to Laurents arrows